# Unable to get property 'location' of undefined or null reference in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm doing very simple programme on react router..but I don't know what's going wrong with this...here is my react router code..

**index.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
    import routes from './routes';


    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
      , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

and here is the routes file ..

**routes.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Route, IndexRouter } from 'react-router';
    import App from './components/app';

    export default(
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    );
```

it shows error something like this...
[image: error]

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: @Sandip Nirmal yes it is without simple App.js file, i have not included in this

Comment: You need to create the history object and pass it to the component, not to pass the imported module.

Comment: Check if the included router version has history module. If not update router to the version which has and try

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`. I've created basic code sandbox for the same You can check code here. https://codesandbox.io/embed/m779xxx4zy.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

const App = props => {
  return <div>HI</div>;
};

export default App;
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./app";

const Routes = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./routes";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.querySelector(".container")
);
```

Comment: it shows error , something like this that **Unable to get property func of undefined or null referance**

Comment: can you make App component to class-based component

Comment: @mrpanchal Done. I am not sure what problem you are facing.

Comment: thanks for giving time ,but I don't know why it is not working on my browser